# Update cli progress bar in async Task

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, task, progress-bar

I have a Swift cli app where an asynchronous `Task` is being used. I want to show a progress bar based on the progress of the task. I'm using the [Progress.swift](https://github.com/jkandzi/Progress.swift) package for the bar.

My code looks like this.

```
var bar = ProgressBar(count: 100)

let waiter = Task {
    do {
        for try await output in session.outputs {
            switch output {
                case .requestProgress(let request, let fractionComplete):
                    bar.setValue(Int(fractionComplete * 100))
            }
        }
    } catch {
        logger.error("Output: ERROR = \(String(describing: error))")
        Foundation.exit(0)
    }
}
```

My problem is now that I get the following error at `bar.setValue()`

`Mutation of captured var 'bar' in concurrently-executing code`.

I'm quite new to swift so please bear with me.

I do understand the error message but how could I work around that and capture to the progress to update my bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use an actor instance like this,

```
actor Bar {
   var progressBar = ProgressBar(count: 100)
   func setValue(_ value: Int) {
       progressBar.setValue(value)
   }
}
        
let bar = Bar()
```

and then in the Task.

```
await bar.setValue(Int(fractionComplete * 100))
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68014274/7349614) anwser.